# Powershell and Thinkvantage Access connections

Tags: windows-7, powershell, thinkpad

I am looking for a way of letting [Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell) control the [Thinkvantage Access connections program](http://support.lenovo.com/en_SE/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS013683) but I can't find any good starting points/guidelines for how to get started. In the end, I want Access connection to default (use instant resume) to my home network at weekends and to the worknetwork at work days.

So my question is, **how do I determine if I can use Powershell to control Thinkvantage Access connections?**

Comment: I have no idea what Thinkvantage is, but one of two things would have to happen. Either Thinkvantage would have to expose an API or you would need to use SendKeys. First, let me say that SendKeys in my personal opinion is almost always a bad plan and should always be a last resort. As for an API, these usually come in one of four variations. Command line interfaces, COM interfaces, .Net Exposed methods and properties, or less likely but the most useful in Powershell, a set of Powershell cmdlets written by the vendor to interface with the app.

Comment: To head off comments, I realize that passing command line parameters is not technically an API, but if the program is written specifically to be controlled that way they essentially are an API.

Comment: command line interface, this would be an example? See http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/Access-Connections-command-line-interface/td-p/153199

Comment: Yes, that would be an example. Is it sufficient to do what you need? I have no clue. As I said I have never used the product. I was just providing general guidance. That is why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: No, it seems to be an example of deploying profiles

Comment: You asked if it is an example of a command line interface. It is.

Comment: You asked if it was sufficient to do what he needed. It isn't.